Jasper Reports - PDF Accessibility for Hyperlinks embedded in StaticText
A .jrxml PDF report uses <staticText> blocks, but the contents may include one or more hyperlinks (<A>) surrounded by text, like the following...
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="364" width="469" height="96">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
            </reportElement>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" markup="html">
                <font fontName="Arial" size="11"/>
            </textElement>
            <text>
                <![CDATA[Some text part 1: 
                <a href="https://www.example.com/faqs/">Latest FAQs</a>.
                Some more text part 2: <font color='blue'><u>
                <a href="https://www.example.com/oldfaqs/">Old FAQs</a>.
                Some final text part 3.]]>
            </text>
        </staticText>

These <A> hyperlinks all fail Adobe's Accessibility check with the error: "Tagged Annotations - Failed".
Elsewhere in the report, I have provided <hyperlinkTooltipExpression> tags to annotations like images, etc. to satisfy the Accessibility requirements.
Questions

Is there a similar solution to provide accessibility to specific pieces of mark-up within <staticText>?

Or, if not, is there a solution to provide accessibility to the whole <staticText> block in one go?

Or, am I going to be forced to break each of these paragraphs down into their constituent elements (text, urls) and arrange them all next to each other in order to provide <hyperlinkTooltipExpression> to these hyperlinks?


